# sub or function not defined error?

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, copy-paste

Can anybody have a look of this code why it gives me the error?

```
Sub orgnize()
    Dim Rng As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Workbook("kob1").Activate
    Worksheets(1).Activate
    Worksheets(1).Range("a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,j1,k1,l1,n1,o1,p1").EntireColumn.Delete
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Set Rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Rng.Copy
    Sheets(2).Range("a1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Workbooks("kob1").Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `"kob1"` ? sheet name or workbook name?

Answer (score 2):

Error shown from this line:

```
Workbook("kob1").Activate
```

So, modify it as follow:

```
Workbooks("kob1").Activate
```

It will work well.